# The locations of (row-wise) minimum elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list representing a 2D matrix, such as this 3 ⨉ 2 one:

```
{{2.1, 1.01}, {0.01, 7.2}, {7.8, 2.0}}
```

Does anyone know how to find the minimum of each row, ideally outputting a new list of 1's where the row minimums are in the original matrix and 0's for all other elements? i.e.

```
{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

The answer should work for any m ⨉ n list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way :

```
f = UnitStep[ Min @ # - #]&;
f /@ {{2.1, 1.01}, {0.01, 7.2}, {7.8, 2.0}}
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}
> ```

Comment: @acl Thanks, your method is also reasonable, +1.

Comment: I came up with `1 - Unitize[Min@# - # & /@ a]` myself.  Yours is cleaner. +1

Answer (score 5):

There is one way:

```
list={{2.1, 1.01}, {0.01, 7.2}, {7.8, 2.0}}
SetAttributes[Equal,Listable]
#==Min[#]&/@list//Boole
(*{{0,1},{1,0},{0,1}}*)
```

Or, as suggested by @swish, without change attributes:

```
list={{2.1, 1.01}, {0.01, 7.2}, {7.8, 2.0}}
Thread[# == Min[#]] & /@ list // Boole
(*{{0,1},{1,0},{0,1}}*)
```

Comment: Maybe better `Thread[# == Min[#]] & /@ list // Boole` instead of setting `Listable` attribute?

Comment: @swish nice tip! Updated

Comment: This is quite neat ;) +1

Comment: nice (and first :) )

Answer (score 5):

Since we have a pile of methods but no timings I'll perform that test.

First my own:

```
mrwizard[a_] := UnitStep[Min /@ a - a]
```

And other functions as I'll use them:

```
murta[list_] := Thread[# == Min[#]] & /@ list // Boole

acl[mat_] := SparseArray[Position[#, Min[#]] -> 1, Length@#] & /@ mat // Normal

artes[a_] := UnitStep[ Min @ # - #]& /@ a

swish[a_] := Thread[KroneckerDelta[Min@#, #]] & /@ a
```

I leave out RiemannZeta's method as it only works on rows of length two, and therefore does not meet the question specification.

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

funcs = {murta, acl, artes, swish, mrwizard};
```

Many short rows:

```
a = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {150000, 3}];

timeAvg[#@a] & /@ funcs
```

> ```
> {0.452, 1.42, 0.515, 0.468, 0.04184}
> ```

```
SameQ @@ (#@a & /@ funcs)
```

> True

Long rows:

```
a = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {100, 30000}];

timeAvg[#@a] & /@ funcs
```

> ```
> {0.827, 0.421, 0.02496, 1.108, 0.1216}
> ```

```
SameQ @@ (#@a & /@ funcs)
```

> True

From this it appears that Artes' method is fastest on a matrix with a limited number of long rows, and my method which is based on his is fastest on a matrix with many short rows.

Comment: Comparative analysis became your speciality +1.

Comment: I decided not to look and ended up with the same answer as you, +1

Comment: Great analysis - now we have elegance and empirical evidence for the best method. (Maybe I jumped the gun when awarding the solution, but it was late and my requirements were related to a small list!)

Comment: I add my timings since they are a bit different (perhaps some random issue) for `a = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {150000, 3}]; timeAvg[#@a] & /@ funcs`  only your approach was better than mine : `{1.201208, 3.915625, 0.102961, 1.341609, 0.0411843}`, while for `a = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {100, 30000}]; timeAvg[#@a] & /@ funcs` returned `{2.277615, 2.496016, 0.078000, 2.839218, 0.121681}`.

Comment: @rnoodle You can always change your Accept.

Comment: @Artes Interesting differences.  Mine are v7 results.

Answer (score 3):

If `mat = {{2.1, 1.01}, {0.01, 7.2}, {7.8, 2.0}}` then

```
SparseArray[Position[#, Min[#]] -> 1, Length@#] & /@ mat // Normal
(*{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}*)
```

If the minimal element appears twice, this returns `1` in both places. Note the `Normal` isn't necessary, it's for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 3):

One more:

```
m = {{2.1, 1.01}, {0.01, 7.2}, {7.8, 2.0}};
Thread[KroneckerDelta[Min@#, #]] & /@ m
(*{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}*)
```

Or:

```
Thread /@ KroneckerDelta /@ (Min /@ m - m)
```

We can get rid of `Thread`:

```
SetAttributes[KroneckerDelta, Listable]
KroneckerDelta[Min@#, #] & /@ m
KroneckerDelta /@ (Min /@ m - m)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m = {{2.1, 1.01}, {0.01, 7.2}, {7.8, 2.0}};
Ordering /@ -m - 1

(* {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}} *)
```